# .net core and Dependency Injection with inheritance

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have this code in a service background worker:

```
public class PortiqueServer : TcpServer
{
    public PortiqueServer(IPAddress address, int port) : base(address, port) { }

    protected override TcpSession CreateSession() =>
        new PortiqueSession(this);

    protected override void OnError(SocketError error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Portique TCP server caught an error with code {error}");
    }
}
```

and I would have this

```
public class PortiqueServer : TcpServer
{
    private readonly ILogger<PortiqueServer> _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public PortiqueServer(
        ILogger<PortiqueServer> logger,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IPAddress address,
        int port) : base(address, port)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override TcpSession CreateSession() => new PortiqueSession(this);

    protected override void OnError(SocketError error)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Portique TCP server caught an error with code {error}");
    }
}
```

The final goal is to call my class like this :

```
var portiqueServer = new PortiqueServer(IPAddress.Any, 2106);
```

I Don't have any possibility to modify TcpServer Class and I don't know how to use dependency injection.

Can you help me please ?
Thank you

Comment: What is it you want to achieve exactly? You want those dependencies to get injected? Some context might be missing here to answer the question.

Comment: Hello @Steven, I would like to inject dependency injection with some other parameters in my contructor. 
I have seen some tutorials but my specific case is that my class is inherited from other class.

Comment: What is preventing you from calling `new PortiqueServer(this.logger, this.configuration, IPAddress.Any, 2106)`?